# ExecutionException The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin, adoptopenjdk

Recently I installed AdoptOpenJDK on all the Linux and Windows Jenkins slaves.
The build is failing because of the following error on Linux slave but it passes on windows slave. The reason for failure is forkCount in maven surefire plugin is set to 2. When it is set to 0, the build passes. We have lot of tests so setting the forkCount to 0 is not an option. The build passes when I use Oracle JDK.

Maven Surefire Plugin version - 3.0.0-M3 
AdoptOpenJDK version - 8u242-b08 
Linux version - Oracle Linux 6.10

Does anybody know why the build fails on AdoptOpenJDK but passes on Oracle JDK?

```
17:29:41 [ERROR] Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
17:29:41 [ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd "...." && ../jre/bin/java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -ea -jar '../target/clover/surefire/surefirebooter744351513939852768.jar' '../target/clover/surefire' 2020-04-11T17-29-39_447-jvmRun4 surefire476358246342757707tmp surefire_32485320874047616644tmp
17:29:41 [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
17:29:41 [ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
17:29:41 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
17:29:41 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.access$600(ForkStarter.java:115)
17:29:41 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter$1.call(ForkStarter.java:371)
17:29:41 [ERROR]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter$1.call(ForkStarter.java:347)
17:29:41 [ERROR]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
17:29:41 [ERROR]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
17:29:41 [ERROR]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
17:29:41 [ERROR]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Try to upgrade to 3.0.0-M4..

Comment: I upgraded the Maven Surefire Plugin version to 3.0.0-M4 but no luck. The build failed again.

Comment: Please show the full pom file and which Maven version do you use?